# Laravel: object or other structures (array, json..) to the view?

Tags: laravel

There are several ways you may pass data to a Laravel Blade view.

In this savvy discussion [Laravel hidden attributes. e.g. Password - security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033925/laravel-hidden-attributes-e-g-password-security) [Antonio Carlos Ribeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1959747/antonio-carlos-ribeiro) states (and i agree) that:

*"you are not supposed to send objects to a view. In the MVC pattern, views should receive data that are relative to them, processed data, not objects, because they don't have to know anything about your business logic."*

I am learning Laravel and everywhere i look i often see examples like:

```
$users = User::all();
return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
```

This one specially comes from the [official documentation.](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#eloquent-orm)

What method should be ideally used?
Do you transform your objects in array or other formats prior to send them to the view?
Do you selectively clean your data from all the unnecessary values prior of pass it to the template engine?
Apart being probably academically wrong, what are the potential risks for passing the object to the view?

Comment: One risk would be that if you have complete access to your Eloquent models in the View you might be tempted to make use of them. Lazy loading would be a common misuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you use following approach

```
$users = User::all();
return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
```

You will get a collection of `User` objects in your model and can use a `loop` to print out all the `User` objects and it's fine, what risk could be doing this, it's upon you, so you should know what should do but if you don't want to pass a collection object then it's also possible to pass only an array of arrays using:

```
$users = User::all()->toArray();
return View::make('users')->with('users', $users);
```

So, you'll get an array of arrays in the view where each child array will contain a perticular user's details. The array may look something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'id' => int 1
      'username' => string 'heera' (length=5)
      'email' => string 'heerasheikh@ymail.com' (length=21)
      'created_at' => string '2014-01-20 06:10:53' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-01-23 10:23:50' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
    'id' => int 2
    'username' => string 'usman' (length=5)
    'email' => string 'mdusyl@yahoo.com' (length=16)
    'created_at' => string '2014-01-20 06:10:53' (length=19)
    'updated_at' => string '2014-01-20 09:06:23' (length=19)
```

But, you can use the Laravel's traditional way and there is no risk at all. Don't follow something blindly, use your sense and ask yourself, what risk it may rise for you. You are only about to loop the collection, nothing else. Now, the choice is your's, if you pass the collection then you can use object notation, i.e. `$user->username` but if you pass an array then you have to use something like `$user['username']`,  that's it.