# using object inside views

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am working on a simple webapp using PHP & codeigniter.
usually in my controller I pass literal values like string and int, received from Model, to View for displaying them.

In some cases my Model return object of a class, and not a literal value.
I know that I can pass objects to View and display their value(by calling the relevant method inside the views),but I think, conceptually its wrong(also its look ODD) to use object and calling their method inside a View, instead of just printing literals.

Anway, my question is, should the controller fetch/prepare the values from the object and pass them to view, or its Ok to pass the object to the view and let the View do this job.

Comment: Answer is: it's Ok :) Cause even you can define view instance as an object

Comment: @Banzay, first thk for the replay. but isn't in MVC architecture, shouldn't the object be separate from the View ?

Comment: @tereško https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html but lets leave it to another discussion. should i pass only literals to Views to keep the view 'clean' from logic ?

Comment: If you are adhering to CodeIgniter's style: yes. If you are actually implementing anything resembling MVC: controllers should not be passing **anything** to the UI layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so After "spying" on other PHP Frameworks:

Yii: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

Symfony: http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html

I saw that its quite common to pass object (or an array of objects) to **View** and iterate on them.
Since its a little bother me passing objects(afraid someone would call object's methods like *update* or *delete*)

so I continue searching and found this post: [Laravel: object or other structures (array, json..) to the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942693/laravel-object-or-other-structures-array-json-to-the-view)

@The_Alpha, suggest to pass an array representation of the object, containing only the properties of the class, which i believe, nice idea

so i will add to Model base class a new method getArray() which will return array representation of the object.

**pseoudo code**

```
class Model{

    ...

    public function getArray(){
        $array = array();
        foreach($this as $key => $value) {
           $array[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $array;
    }

    ...
}
```

and now in my controller i could easily do:

**pseoudo code**

```
class MyController extends Controller{

    ...

    public function action(){

        $array = $this->model->getArray(); // fetch array representation of model
        $this->view('myview',$array);      // pass the array to view for rendering
    }

    ...
}
```

Thx for everyone on the help

Answer (score 0):

in this case "object" is just a name for a type of data structure. especially when you get results from a Model that is querying a database -- you have a choice whether to return those database results as an "array" or an "object" .

there's times that you have to iterate over data in the view. whether its an array or an object is not a big deal.

if you have a controller "prepare the data" in some way then you will have a "Fat" controller. versus having the model prepare the data => Thin controller.

you want the controller to show the appropriate view based on the data you got. for example a search -- if no results come back then you would show a "no results please try again" view. if results come back then you would pass those results to a view which can display.

in other words you are not checking if results came back in the view code. if you call a results view, you have already confirmed there are valid results to display.

Controllers call the Views. Views can call other views. Views can also include calls to Models but that is frowned on because it can get messy and is harder to debug.